# How to merge and replace objects from two arrays based on a key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have two array object(arrayList1,arrayList2). Just I am trying to merge those two arrays into one array object.
The following terms I used.

- Both array merged into one array based on key-name is **type**.
- arrayList2 values will be overwrite the arrayList1.
- I Got the expected output but I am worying to do with efficient and performance way..

Can someone please simplify my code..

Note :

- It would be great if using Array.reduce function and without use any plugin/library..
- I added the smaple input for understanding. The element order will be change and size of both array's will change.

```js
const arrayList1 = [
    { type: "A", any: 11, other: "ab", props: "1" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bc", props: "2" }, // same type
    { type: "C", any: 33, other: "df", props: "3" }
];
 
const arrayList2 = [
    { type: "D", any: 44, other: "aa", props: "11" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bb", props: "2----2" , x: 10}, // same type
    { type: "E", any: 44, other: "cc", props: "33" }
];

result = arrayList2.reduce(function (arr1, arr2) {
  let isMatchFound = false;
  arr1.forEach(function (list) {
    if (arr2.type == list.type) {
      list = Object.assign(list, arr2);
      isMatchFound = true;
    }
  });
  if (!isMatchFound) {
    arr1.push(arr2);
  }
  return arr1;
}, arrayList1);

console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be? What should `result` be?

Comment: What is the `use case` here. What is the typical size of `list 1` and `list 2`? Are they always equal? I won't be too worried about performance until it is a problem. When the codebase is huge, bottlenecks are often some where else. Machine can deal with `loops` etc pretty efficiently these days.

Comment: @JackBashford - I got the expected output. Just want to reduce the code with efficient and performance way.

Comment: @SamuelToh, The size of 'list-1' and 'list-2' will be change.. Mostly the format of list1, list2 will be differ. Just I added smaple json for understanding...

Comment: @RSKMR Is ordering of elements fixed i.e. first elements of arrayList1 and then arrayList2?

Comment: @Ashish - no, The order will be change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use `.reduce()` and `Object.values()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const arrayList1 = [
    { type: "A", any: 11, other: "ab", props: "1" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bc", props: "2" }, // same type
    { type: "C", any: 33, other: "df", props: "3" }
];
 
const arrayList2 = [
    { type: "D", any: 44, other: "aa", props: "11" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bb", props: "2----2" , x: 10}, // same type
    { type: "E", any: 44, other: "cc", props: "33" }
];

const result = Object.values(
   [].concat(arrayList1, arrayList2)
     .reduce((r, c) => (r[c.type] = Object.assign((r[c.type] || {}), c), r), {})
);
                 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since Object.values [does not guarantee to come in any particular order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties) I would suggest using a Map instead: `[
    ...[]
        .concat(arrayList1, arrayList2)
        .reduce((r, c) => 
          r.set(c.type, Object.assign(r.get(c.type) || {}, c)), r, new Map())
        .values(),
];`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const array1 = [
    { type: "A", any: 11, other: "ab", props: "1" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bc", props: "2" }, // same type
    { type: "C", any: 33, other: "df", props: "3" }
];
 
const array2 = [
    { type: "D", any: 44, other: "aa", props: "11" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bb", props: "2----2" , x: 10}, // same type
    { type: "E", any: 44, other: "cc", props: "33" }
];

const mapped = array1.reduce((a,t)=> (a[t.type] = t, a), {}),
      mapped2 = array2.reduce((a,t)=> (a[t.type] = t, a), {})

console.log(Object.values({...mapped, ...mapped2}))
```

Comment: See comment at Mohammad Usman answer; the order is not guaranteed in Object.values so if order is important and you want it guaranteed then it's better to use Map.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to make your code smaller:

```js
const arrayList1 = [
    { type: "A", any: 11, other: "ab", props: "1" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bc", props: "2" }, // same type
    { type: "C", any: 33, other: "df", props: "3" }
];
 
const arrayList2 = [
    { type: "D", any: 44, other: "aa", props: "11" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bb", props: "2----2" , x: 10}, // same type
    { type: "E", any: 44, other: "cc", props: "33" }
];

result = arrayList2.reduce(function(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.find(({ type }) => type == arr2.type)) {
    arr1[arr1.indexOf(arr1.find(({ type }) => type == arr2.type))] = Object.assign(arr1.find(({ type }) => type == arr2.type), arr2);
    arr1.push(arr2);
  }
  return arr1;
}, arrayList1);

console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: The expected output not met. Please check my output in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont exactly need arrayList1 before arrayList2, you can use this one liner simple approach.
What I have done is I have destructured all elements arrayList2 and only those elements of arrayList1 whose key does not exist in arrayList1.

P.S. the problem with `reduce` is you have to reduce the largest array otherwise you will miss out the elements of bigger Array.

```js
const arrayList1 = [
    { type: "A", any: 11, other: "ab", props: "1" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bc", props: "2" }, // same type
    { type: "C", any: 33, other: "df", props: "3" }
];
 
const arrayList2 = [
    { type: "D", any: 44, other: "aa", props: "11" },
    { type: "B", any: 22, other: "bb", props: "2----2" , x: 10}, // same type
    { type: "E", any: 44, other: "cc", props: "33" }
];
const output = [...arrayList2, ...arrayList1.filter(el1 => !arrayList2.some(el2 => el2.type === el1.type))]
//[].concat(arrayList2, arrayList1.filter(el1 => !arrayList2.some(el2 => el2.type === el1.type)))

console.log(output)
```