# Update existing item or add new item to reducer | React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a requirement where I'll receive an array of objects. I've to check if the received array of objects already present in the store. If yes then I want to update the new object with old object, else I want to add the new element to the store.

```
const initialState = {
    ....
    ....
    UserChangedData : {
        ....
        ....
        changedData: []
    }
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        ....
        ....
        ....
        case SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA:
            // if there is no userChangedData this condition will run initially
            if (state.UserChangedData.changedData.length === 0) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    UserChangedData: {
                        ...state.UserChangedData,
                        changedData: [...action.payload]
                    }
                };
            }

            // check if the user item already exists update them. if user item doesn't exists then add 
            // item to UserChangedData's changedData array with existing data. to check if the item 
            // exists or not we can use id.

           // the object which I receive will be an array of object(s)

            // scenario 1 Initial data.
           // [{id:1 , name: "john", gender: "Male"}, {id:2 , name: "peter", gender: "Male"}, {id:3 , 
           //  name: "Natalie", gender: "Female"}, {id:4 , name: "Nicole", gender:"Female"}]

            // scenario 2 : user edited one object with id 1 so update the whole object where the inital 
           // changedData  
           //  example data : [{id:1 , name: "Logan", gender: "Male"}]

           // scenario 3: user edited id: 1  and added a new object with id: 8 so update previous id: 1 
           // with new id: 1 object data and also add new object id: 8 data to changedData array.
           // id: 8 
           // example data: [{id:1 , name: "Jane", gender: "Female"}, {id:8 , name: "Jane", 
           //                 gender:"Female"}
```

I've tried many logic none of them worked can anyone please suggest me a logic of the above scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to merge and replace state.UserChangedData.changedData with the action.payload  based on their id values.

You can use following reducer to achieve what you want:

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA:
      let updatedChangeData = Object.values(
        []
          .concat(state.UserChangedData.changedData, action.payload)
          .reduce(
            (r, c) => ((r[c.id] = Object.assign(r[c.id] || {}, c)), r),
            {}
          )
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        UserChangedData: {
          ...state.UserChangedData,
          changedData: updatedChangeData
        }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The idea is taken from this post:

[How to merge and replace objects from two arrays based on a key in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321579/how-to-merge-and-replace-objects-from-two-arrays-based-on-a-key-in-javascript)

Here is  full code to play with it in a standalone node app:

```
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;

const SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA = "SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA";

const initialState = {
  UserChangedData: {
    changedData: []
  }
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA:
      let updatedChangeData = Object.values(
        []
          .concat(state.UserChangedData.changedData, action.payload)
          .reduce(
            (r, c) => ((r[c.id] = Object.assign(r[c.id] || {}, c)), r),
            {}
          )
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        UserChangedData: {
          ...state.UserChangedData,
          changedData: updatedChangeData
        }
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("[Subscription]", store.getState().UserChangedData.changedData);
});

store.dispatch({
  type: SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA,
  payload: [{ id: 1, title: "A" }]
});

store.dispatch({
  type: SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA,
  payload: [{ id: 2, title: "B" }]
});

store.dispatch({
  type: SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA,
  payload: [{ id: 1, title: "AA" }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked like a charm! Could you please just explain to me the updatedChangeData part it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @AashayAmballi  it just merges and replaces two arrays based on id, I know that it is not very easy to understand this code:(  but does the work:)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#immutable-update-patterns) in the Redux documentation.

Your scenario:

- your state is correctly initialized to empty array, hence your `state.UserChangedData.changedData` is always an array
- in your `case SET_USER_BUCKET_LIST_DATA:` you should create the new variable `let newStateChangedData = [...state.UserChangedData.changedData]`
- loop over all items in `action.payload` and for each item look into `state.UserChangedData.changedData` if it is there

  - if it is not there, add it with use of [Inserting and Removing Items in Arrays](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays) recipe (add item in `newStateChangedData`)
  - if it is there, update it with use of [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) recipe (update item in `newStateChangedData`)
- then always update your state this way (the `if` in your solution should not be there):

```js
return {
    ...state,
    UserChangedData: {
        ...state.UserChangedData,
        changedData: newStateChangedData
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: How should I loop through action.payload using traditional for loop or map which will return an array. Can you please show me a code example.

Comment: No map, some traditional for loop will be ok. You should change your `newStateChangedData` in each loop, e.g. `newStateChangedData = [...newStateChangedData, newAddedItem]`

Comment: Since I'm having a copy of changedData, is it okay to mutate the copy of the array?

Comment: No you should do it with immutable patterns, I directed you to the redux documentation. This `newStateChangedData = [...newStateChangedData, newAddedItem]` is not mutatating this is throwing old value away and setting new value.

Comment: Do you know any simpler solution than the above solution which SuleymanSah gave.